# Data Contract Json serialization extra "_type" and "Name Space" removal

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have requirement to serialize a file and store it to the server from Windows app and iphone App.
For windows app, I am using the WPF application and for Iphone app,I am using Xamarin.Iphone serialized file should read the Desktop app and vice versa.

I am using the same model classes for both xamarin ios and WPF app.Also I am using the same serialization methods(DataContractJson Serialization methods)on both ends.

But Ican see Xamarin  seralized file  is contains the "_type" and "Name Space" Information.But the same code doesn't create the Namespace and type information in WPF app.This makes issues while deserializing" the Xamarin serialized file from WPF app.

So how can i remove this extra "_type" and "Name Space"information from the Xmarin ios? 
Below is the sample code.

```
List<Child> lsts = new List<Child>(){new Child{count=1,letter="a"},
            new Child{count=1,letter="b"}, 
            new Child{count=2,letter="b"}, 
            new Child{count=3,letter="d"}, 
            new Child{count=4,letter="e"}};

        data data = new data { Id = 1, Name = "hai2", lstData = lsts };

        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(data));


        DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(data));

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        js.WriteObject(ms, data);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
        sr.BaseStream.Position = 0;
        string result = sr.ReadToEnd();



     public class data
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<Child> lstData { get; set; }
    }


    public class Child
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int count { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string letter { get; set; }

    }
```

Outputs from the two platforms are shown below.

```
"{\"Id\":1,\"Name\":\"hai2\",\"lstData\":[{\"__type\":\"Child:#WBid.WBidiPad.Model\",\"count\":1,\"letter\":\"a\"},{\"__type\":\"Child:#WBid.WBidiPad.Model\",\"count\":1,\"letter\":\"b\"},{\"__type\":\"Child:#WBid.WBidiPad.Model\",\"count\":2,\"letter\":\"b\"},{\"__type\":\"Child:#WBid.WBidiPad.Model\",\"count\":3,\"letter\":\"d\"},{\"__type\":\"Child:#WBid.WBidiPad.Model\",\"count\":4,\"letter\":\"e\"}]}"


"{\"Id\":1,\"Name\":\"hai2\",\"lstData\":[{\"count\":1,\"letter\":\"a\"},{\"count\":1,\"letter\":\"b\"},{\"count\":2,\"letter\":\"b\"},{\"count\":3,\"letter\":\"d\"},{\"count\":4,\"letter\":\"e\"}]}"
```

Comment: What happens if you change ''lsts'' from `List<Child>` to `Child[]`? Also, this doesn't really pertain to your question, but you should consider using Json.NET to serialize/deserialize. It works in Xamarin iOS and is faster (and maybe less problematic) than DataContractJsonSerializer